# Integration with iOS calendars API

Tags: ios, calendar

I am going to integrate with iOS calendars for generating links and sending them to my clients. Can I integrate without using Eventkit or any framework?

Comment: Why do you want to achieve it without Eventkit or any other framework?

Comment: Because I am going to use web-sevice in my platform